# Dismiss Button in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, flash-message

i'm using bootstrap and Devise and trying to get a dismiss button on the Flash Messages.
I tried a lot of different stuff but i'm not getting the button to appear right.

My Code for the moment is:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
<% end %>
```

Somewhere in there, somehow, i must add the dismiss button code from bootstrap which is:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass block to content_tag like this:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
 <%= content_tag(:div, class: "alert alert-#{name}") do%>
    <%=msg%>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
 <%end%>

<% end %>
```